# Using Pandas shift with multi-index

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have am trying to make a simple stock portfolio tracker. I start with $100k dollars and invest based on weights in two stocks. Each month, I want to sell the stock and then set the new starting dollars (shares bought in last period * current price) and reinvest in the two stocks again based on this months weights.

I figured out how to calculate the Shares bought each period thanks to some previous SO help, but I'm have trouble update the starting balance for each date. I think due to order of operations, it needs to be done as a loop, but having trouble getting the shift to work.

Start of my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[datetime(year=2017, day=01, month=01), 100000, 'AAPL', 0.6, 1000],
                        [datetime(year=2017, day=01, month=01), 100000, 'GOOG', 0.4, 1200],
                        [datetime(year=2017, day=01, month=02), 100000, 'AAPL', 0.7, 1400],
                        [datetime(year=2017, day=01, month=02), 100000, 'GOOG', 0.3, 1300],
                        [datetime(year=2017, day=01, month=03), 100000, 'AAPL', 0.8, 980],
                        [datetime(year=2017, day=01, month=03), 100000, 'GOOG', 0.2, 1400]
                        ],
                  columns=['Date', 'Dollars Available', 'Stock', 'Weight', 'Price'])

df = df.set_index(['Date', 'Dollars Available', 'Stock'])
df['Shares Bought'] = (df.index.get_level_values('Dollars Available') * df['Weight']).values / df['Price'].values
```

So far, I've gotten to here. As you can see, the starting balance is the same for each date.

```
                                    Weight  Price  Shares Bought
Date       Dollars Available Stock                              
2017-01-01 100000            AAPL      0.6   1000      60.000000
                             GOOG      0.4   1200      33.333333
2017-02-01 100000            AAPL      0.7   1400      50.000000
                             GOOG      0.3   1300      23.076923
2017-03-01 100000            AAPL      0.8    980      81.632653
                             GOOG      0.2   1400      14.285714
```

Desired Output:

```
                                        Weight  Price  Shares Bought
Date       Dollars Available Stock                              
2017-01-01 10000.00          AAPL      0.6   1000          60.00
                             GOOG      0.4   1200          33.33
2017-02-01 127333.33         AAPL      0.7   1400          63.66
                             GOOG      0.3   1300          29.38
2017-03-01 103531.79         AAPL      0.8    980          73.95
                             GOOG      0.2   1400          22.19
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about organizing your data this way (I've left off 2017-03-01 because you don't show prices for that date and it makes the example more concise):

```
Date        AAPL Return  GOOG Return  AAPL Weight  GOOG Weight
2017-01-01          1.4        1.083          0.6          0.4
2017-02-01          0.7        1.077          0.7          0.3
```

Above, Return is (close price / open price).

Now multiply for each stock:

```
Date        AAPL WgtRet  GOOG WgtRet  Sum WgtRet  Cum WgtRet
2017-01-01         0.84       0.4332      1.2732      1.2732
2017-02-01         0.49       0.3231      0.8131      1.0352
```

Above, Sum WgtRet is like sum(axis=1), and Cum WgtRet is like cumprod(Sum WgtRet).

Now, simply take your starting capital and multiply by Cum WgtRet to get the month-end balances:

```
Date        End Balance
2017-01-01  127320
2017-02-01  103520
```

Each of the above operations is easily done in vectorized form, without loops.  You can "pivot" the stock column from row labels to column labels at the beginning.

If you want to add the "Shares Bought" columns, just shift(1) the End Balance to make a Begin Balance column, and multiply by the weights.

Comment: Thank you. This looks promising, but it much above my pandas skill level. What is the best way to get the data even set up like your first dataframe? My thought was to use something like `df.groupby(['Stock'])['Price'].shift(-1)/df.groupby(['Stock'])['Price']` but I am getting errors

Comment: After creating the DataFrame, do `df.set_index(['Date', 'Stock'], inplace=True)` then `df.Weight.unstack()` to get weight per stock, `px = df.Price.unstack()` for prices, then `px / px.shift()` to get the returns.  Add each new column to a single DataFrame whose index is just Date.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to calculate the Dollars

```
df['New1']=((1+df.groupby('Stock').Price.pct_change())).shift(-2)*df.Weight

df.groupby('Date').New1.sum().cumprod().mul(100000).shift().fillna(100000)
Out[288]: 
Date
2017-01-01    100000.000000
2017-02-01    127333.333333
2017-03-01    103531.794872
Name: New1, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you. What am I doing wrong? I only see the first two rows.

Comment: @user2242044 ummm. what you mean first two row ?

Comment: sorry nevermind. I shortened my df to two months when I tried your code. Just me being stupid :)

Comment: @user2242044 ahha happy coding